# My Reach Has Jumped

Tags: discussion, people-reached

So, I read the meta-blog about [reach](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244534/were-working-on-a-new-stat-to-help-convey-the-reach-of-your-posts-here) calculation, but I'm curious.

My reach as of.. last week? I don't know the exact date, but it's quite recent, was 576k, and all of a sudden today, it's +400,000 to 976k. I know I've gotten a few votes, but how does that yield 400k? That's quite a significant number!

Comment: My Flabber Has Gasted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like it's from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13968494/how-to-delete-a-column-from-a-table-in-mysql/13968529#13968529).

It just recently got another upvote, which put it at 5. That's the cutoff to qualify it for being counted as part of your "people reached". Since the post has ~380,000 views, that matches up with the increase you see.

Although now it's gotten a downvote, and you lost those 380,000 people reached. So... sorry.

Comment: Makes sense. I wonder why this search didn't find it though http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A774078+is%3Aanswer+views%3A10000

Comment: Oh my god that answer does not deserve 380k reach LOL

Comment: Wow… Answer clean-up on aisle 3, please! One question does not need that many duplicate answers. And who in the world is upvoting them? I mean, seriously, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41635804/366904) was posted only a few days ago, is a complete rehash of all the other older answers, and doesn't even format the code correctly.

Comment: It's actually funny one person downvoted just mine so I would lose the reach XD (not worried about it)