# Why has my 'people reached' number jumped so quickly?

Tags: discussion

I've seen [My Reach Has Jumped](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/342934/my-reach-has-jumped), and [Impact score doubled overnight. A bug?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/310676/impact-score-doubled-overnight-a-bug). I know you may think that this is a possible duplicate, so I will tell you why it is not.

---

I read the [rules](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244534/were-working-on-a-new-stat-to-help-convey-the-reach-of-your-posts-here) on how you get a jump in people reached and these are the rules.

- Questions

  - Non-deleted only
- Answers - Views of the parent question for answers that are:

  - Non-deleted AND
  - Score > 0 AND
  - Not self-answers AND
  - Also meeting one or more of the following criteria:

    - In the top 3 answers OR
    - Is the Accepted Answer OR
    - Score at least 5 OR
    - Has at least 20% of the total vote count

And based on [Impact score doubled overnight. A bug?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/310676/impact-score-doubled-overnight-a-bug)  answer, it says:

> The rules for impact state that an answer needs 5 upvotes to count, hence your impact jumped by a little over 84k.

I did not fulfill this rule, so why am I getting leap jump of people reached?

Comment: Make sure that the sorting is "Highest score" to see that it's now in the top 3 answers. Other sortings may not work well.

Answer (score 3):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73017163/1038015) is in the top 3 answers and the question has 5K views.

There are more than 3 answers on that question and old the 3rd answer has 2 votes. Your answer didn't make it into the top 3 until it scored 3 which was today.

Your answer therefore fulfils the first of the four alternate criteria in the last section. It does not need to fulfil all of them that's why it says OR after each bullet point.

Comment: Old the 3rd answer?